# Time Complexity for Modulus in Nested Loops

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o, modulo

```
sum=0;
for(i=1; i<n;i++)
   for( j = 1; j < i * i; j++ ) 
      if( j % i == 0 )
        for( k = 0; k < j; k++ ) 
             sum++;
```

I know that the outer most loop executes n time, the next loop n^2 times, but how do I factor the j%i with the loop? The correct answer is O(N^4), but I am not sure how that is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that the `k` loop only executes when `j` is divisible by `i` (this is where the modulo comes in), we can figure out how many times `k` loops at every `i` loop:

- `i = 2, j:1..4`: loops `2` times (`j=2`).
- `i = 3, j:1..9`: loops `3 + 6` times (`j=3,6`).
- `i = 4, j:1..16`: loops `4 + 8 + 12` times (`j=4,8,12`).
- ...
- `i = n, j:1..n*n`: loops `n + 2n + ... (n - 1) * n`

  - Or `Sum(k * n, k = 1, n - 1)` = `n^2 * (n - 1) / 2` times.

I realize that this should stop at `i = n - 1`, but this is enough to show the growth.

This means that our complexity is that of

```
2 + (3 + 6) + (4 + 8 + 12) + ... + (n^2 * (n - 1) / 2)
=Sum(
  i^2 * (i - 1) / 2, 
  i = 2, n - 1
)
=Sum(
  (i^3 - i^2) / 2, 
  i = 2, n - 1
)
```

Since the `i^3` term dominates and the division by 2 doesn't matter, this has the same time complexity as

```
Sum(i^3, i=2, n - 1)
```

Which is `O(n^4)`.